# How to solve this recurrence relation $ f(x, 0)=3 x \text { and } f(x, n+1)=f(f(x, n), n)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Given that $f(x, 0)=3 x \text { and } f(x, n+1)=f(f(x, n), n)$,
find an explicit formula for $f(x, y)$. Use this formula to calculate $f(2005,3)$.

What topics do I need to learn to solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Use MathJax. Please use more descriptive titles. Please provide context.

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x=2005$ and $n=2$, then
$f(2005,3)=f(f(2005, 2), 2)$

Take $x=2005$ and $n=1$, then
$f(2005,2)=f(f(2005, 1), 1)$

Take $x=2005$ and $n=0$, then
$f(2005,1)=f(f(2005, 0), 0)$

Now
$f(2005,0)=3 \times 2005=6015$

Thus
$f(2005,1)=f(f(2005, 0), 0)=f(6015, 0)=3 \times 6015=18045$

$f(2005,2)=f(f(2005, 1), 1)=f(18045, 0)=3 \times 18045=54135$

$f(2005,3)=f(f(2005, 2), 2)=f(54135, 0)=3 \times 54135=162405$

In general:
$$f(x, 0)=3x, f(x, 1)=3^2x, ... , f(x, n)=3^{n+1}x$$

$$f(2005, 3)=3^{4}*2005=162405$$

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards